# Interacting OpenLayers with GeoServer

Tags: openlayers

I am new to OpenLayers. I need guidance on below.

I am able to create map using OpenLayers and able to create polygon interactions on the map and able to extract as GeoJSON object with coordinates.

Now I need to send this GeoJSON request to my GeoServer to get the intersected grids on the OpenLayers (grids are configured in GeoServer).

How can I achieve this using RESTful API?

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this using the GeoServer REST API. GeoServer provides a REST API to allow clients to manage the GeoServer's data and settings not interact with the actual data.

To send and receive data you need to look at the [WFS and WFS-T standards](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs).

Comment: Hi Ian,
Thanks for your response. Actually my requirement is below. We are using GeoJson to show the Map in the front-end where can i draw polygons using OpenLayer. We have stored Grid files in Geo-Server.

When we draw the polygon in the front-end and sent to Geo-Server Geo-server should response with grids selected in polygon by intersecting polygon with grid and respond back to grid details.

Is this possible ? in OpenLayers with Geo-Server. Kindly advise on this.

Comment: You need to use the edit link to update your question if this doesn't answer your issue. But yes WFS will do this for you